# Xalan (XSLT) translate method translating more than it should

Tags: xml, xslt, xalan

I seem to be having an issue with Xalan's translate method. 
I have the following code:

`translate(translate(string(name),'&lt;sup&gt;',''),'&lt;/sup&gt;','')`

This is used to remove `<sup>` and `</sup>` from string(name). Unfortunately when I do that, it seems to remove s, u and p from the names as well.
So names like `sony Braiva <sup>tm</sup>` become `ony bravia tm`

Thanks for you help in advance :)

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for an explanation and for two XSLT 1.0 solutions and one XSLT 2.0 solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you said that the translate() function is successfully removing `<sup>` and `</sup>`, I am assuming that `<sup>` is not an element in the XML document, but is encoded as text.

**The translate() function is defined to substitute individual characters and generally isn't suitable for string replacement** when the string length is greater than 1.

It is possible to write and use a general string replacement recursive template/function in XSLT.

XSLT 2.0 programmers can use the standard XPath 2.0 function replace().

**In your particular case even this this may be sufficient:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:variable name="vPart1" select=
   "substring-before(., '&lt;sup>')"/>

  <xsl:value-of select="$vPart1"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vPart2" select=
   "substring-before(substring-after(., '&lt;sup>'),
                     '&lt;/sup>'
                     )"/>

  <xsl:value-of select="$vPart2"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vPart3" select=
   "substring-after(., '&lt;/sup>')"/>

  <xsl:value-of select="$vPart3"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<name>
 <![CDATA[sony Braiva <sup>tm</sup> xxx]]>
</name>
```

**the wanted result is produced**:

```
<name>
sony Braiva tm xxx
</name>
```

**Alternatively, here is the full-blown recursive template solution:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:variable name="vFirstReplacement">
      <xsl:call-template name="replace">
       <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="."/>
       <xsl:with-param name="pPattern"
         select="'&lt;sup>'"/>
       <xsl:with-param name="pReplacement" select="''"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:call-template name="replace">
   <xsl:with-param name="pText"
        select="$vFirstReplacement"/>
   <xsl:with-param name="pPattern"
     select="'&lt;/sup>'"/>
   <xsl:with-param name="pReplacement" select="''"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="replace">
  <xsl:param name="pText"/>
  <xsl:param name="pPattern"/>
  <xsl:param name="pReplacement"/>

  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="not(contains($pText, $pPattern))">
    <xsl:value-of select="$pText"/>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
     <xsl:value-of select=
      "substring-before($pText, $pPattern)"/>

     <xsl:value-of select="$pReplacement"/>

     <xsl:call-template name="replace">
      <xsl:with-param name="pText" select=
       "substring-after($pText, $pPattern)"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="pPattern"
           select="$pPattern"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="pReplacement"
           select="$pReplacement"/>
     </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on this XML document**:

```
<name>
 <![CDATA[sony Braiva <sup>tm</sup> xxx]]>
</name>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<name>
 sony Braiva tm xxx
</name>
```

**Finally, here is the XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:value-of select=
   "replace(
            replace(., '&lt;sup>', ''),
            '&lt;/sup>',
            ''
            )
   "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks. This helps! Wow...seriously out of words. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr version:** Don't manipulate html or xml as strings if you can possibly avoid it. Do it in XSLT.

I'm assuming that what you have is some element contains something like

```
<name>Sony Braiva <sup>tm</sup></name>
```

So it looks like you've got a parsed XML document already in XSLT. Then, you're turning around and trying to use string manipulation to pull some tags out. That's a bad idea; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) about matching tags. XSLT is exactly for this sort of manipulation, so use it! (If my assumption is wrong and that <sup>tm</sup> is entity-ized or in a CDATA section or whatever, that's different I guess.)

So, first. If you want to **strip *all* tags out of name leaving just the text**, you can do

```
<xsl:value-of select="name" />
```

which would give:

```
Sony Braiva tm
```

If, on the other hand, you want to **strip all sup tags and their content**, you would first elsewhere define a template matching sup (and do the same with anything you want to rip out, e.g. script tags, img tags, whatever):

```
<xsl:template match="sup" /> <!-- replace sup with nothing -->
```

And then you can apply

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="name" />
```

If you really wanted, you could even do something like this and replace that HTML with a nice unicode symbol. It might be a good idea to place this in a different mode and use that mode to eliminate all other tags.

```
<xsl:template match="sup" mode="mangle-name">
  <xsl:if test="'tm' = string(.)">
  &#8482;
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Later, somewhere else: -->
<xsl:apply-templates select="name" mode="mangle-name" />
```

Disclaimer on all of this: It's standard XSLT (probably 1.0 even), but I've only tried it in an online Saxon parser and not in Xalan.